# Sharepoint Excel Web Access Web Part double scrollbars

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, excel

This has been very annoying for me. I searched for hours now in order to solve this. However I have not been able to find a satisfying solution.

On a SP Webpart page I have added an Excel Web Access Webpart. I am trying to display a named range (which works fine). I have adjusted all settings so that it looks clean for a presentation on a dashboard.

The remaining problem however is the double scrollbars that appear vertically:

[image]

By using Chrome developer tools I have been able to identify the html elements

`class="ewr-sheetcontainer ewr-grdblkcontainer ewa-scrollbars"`

and by altering to `overflow:hidden` I have been able to remove the inner scrollbars (both horizontally and vertically). However, the outer scroll bar (dark grey in the picture above) remains.

I assume it is some kind of webpart scrollbar that can be removed by adjusting the webpart-size correctly. However I cannot figure out how (adjusting the "appearance" to fixed pixels or automatic has not helped).

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to verify the following things for troubleshooting:

Open the page in another browser like IE and compare the results.

Add the site to the trusted site and add the site to compatibility view.

Test with a new file with the Excel Web Access web part and compare the results.

Besides, hiding scrollbars in excel services web part for your reference:

https://dataonwheels.wordpress.com/2015/03/17/excel-tip-21-hiding-scrollbars-in-excel-services-web-part/

Comment: I tried the whole thing in IE and that seems to work. Adding the site as trusted site did not make a difference in Chrome, though. I also tried with a new file, but did not achieve any improvement there. What could be the difference between IE and Chrome in this case?

Comment: This might be the compatibility issue about SharePoint with chrome. It is recommend  to use SharePoint with IE.